# display fields in ACF plugin WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF plugin for my wordpress website https://www.advancedcustomfields.com

I created fields for page, and use `the_field("field_name")` and `get_field("field_name")` in page.php file in theme, but it show value of field, not html render.

For example field type is image, I want it display as `<img src="$field_value">` not `$field_value` string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In ACF use this code.

```
<img src="<?php the_field('ACF filed name') ?>" alt="image">
```

Use image filed in ACF backed and select the Image URL. Check the screenshot for more details.  https://prnt.sc/nauf26.

Check this link for more details https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an image object when dealing with images in ACF unless you’re using it for a background image therefore only using the URL.

This is because it gives you access to limiting sizes, providing an accurate alt tag etc.

Please see the below:

```
<?php
    $image = get_field('field_name');
?>

<img alt="<?php echo $image['alt'];>" src="<?php echo $image['url'];>">
```

For more information on the image field and how to use it within repeater and flexible fields [click here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/).